# How to add a python script as an executable shortcut to launcher?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, shortcuts, executable

I have managed to add .sh files as launcher shortcuts. Now, I want to add a python script
in the launcher as shortcut.

I want it to be executed like when it would get executed in the terminal when the following command is run:

```
python pythonscript.py
```

Can it also be added in the launcher?

How can I do it?

Comment: Umm...downvote??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=python
```

don't forget to add above line if doesn't exists(if already exists then append `name` from `[ ]`)

```
[python Shortcut Group]
Name=Python
Exec=python /path/to/script/script.py
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Comment: Where to add this? in a new .desktop file?

Comment: You can also add a bang line to the very top of your script to get rid of python call. A good bang line could be:

    #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: in existing one or you can create launcher having so many quick list.

Comment: @jasmines you are right.

Comment: @jasmines...Oh that workd amazingly..!!

Comment: @virpara...Oh thanx again..!! You r always der 4 me..!! ;) Thanx :p

Comment: If smb doesn't understand where to add this - read http://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut