# Canon (MG 5350) scangear doesn't appear in dash

Tags: unity-dash, canon, pixma

I recently downloaded the Ubuntu scangear driver from their website for my canon pixma MG5350 3 in one printer. I downloaded the debian package and installed it trough the terminal, however I can't seem to find the app himself.

I searched for it trough dash and other scanning apps didn't work from the beginning (like Xsane and simple scan), since they don't seem to recognize my printer/scanner.

The terminal seemed to install the driver/program just fine; it didn't encounter any errors. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select [Create] - [ScanGear MP...] from the [File] menu in Gimp

or run in terminal: `scangearmp`

form their documentation:

> Only GIMP can start ScanGear. No other application software can start ScanGear.
>   If GIMP is not installed, you must install the software.

Answer (score 11):

If you want ScangearMP to appear in the Dash, you can create a .desktop file for it.

Copy the following into a text editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ScanGear MP
Comment=Cannon's scanner software
Exec=scangearmp
Icon=scanner
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;Graphics;Scanning;
```

Save the file with filename scangearmp.desktop

To use the desktop file from the Dash you will need to copy it to `/usr/share/applications` for any user to be able to use it (you will need administrator permissions) or to `~/.local/share/applications` (where ~ means your user directory) if you just want it to be available for one user.

Source: adapted from [Creating a .desktop file for a new application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application), and as I've used myself.

Notes:

### Version

Refers to the .desktop file version, not to the program version.

### Name

The name that should be displayed on the menu.

### Exec

The path to the executable. As scangearmp installs into /usr/bin (in the default path) I've left off the full path, which works for me.

### Icon

The path to the icon file that will be used in the Dash. I've used a generic icon name that's also used for Simple Scan.