# How does one install Canon MG series printer / scanner

Tags: printing, canon

We recently purchased a Canon printer for our home. My wife's works fine because she uses a Mac.

I cannot find the drivers for the Canon MG7520 printer series printer. How does one install that particular printer so i can print it?

P.s. This is for my ubuntu 14.04 computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver)

Answer (score 2):

Canon printers all seem to share the same debian driver. I test this with the Canon MG7520 printer on Ubuntu 14.04.

### Printer Installation Steps

Download the debian driver found here on Canon's Website:

http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100626502.html

Extract the tar.gz file and then run the install.sh file:

```
tar -xvf cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb
./install.sh
```

### Installing the scanner

The scanner can be found here:
http://support-ph.canon-asia.com/contents/PH/EN/0100627102.html

Repeat the same steps:

- Download the tar file
- Extract
- run ./install.sh file

After installing the scanner run:

`scangearmp2` to start the scanner software. It'll scan for your scanner.

Sources:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251206

Comment: The link here for the printer driver 5.00 works well - however if you download the driver version 5.20 from Canon's site it seems unable to find the printer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want ScangearMP to appear in the Dash, you can create a .desktop file for it.

Copy the following into a text editor:

> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Version=1.0
>
> Name=ScanGear2 MP
>
> Comment=Cannon's scanner software
>
> Exec=/usr/bin/scangearmp2
>
> Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/devices/scanner.png
>
> Terminal=false
>
> Type=Application
>
> Categories=Utility;Application;Graphics;Scanning;

Save the file with filename scangearmp.desktop

To use the desktop file from the Dash you will need to copy it to /usr/share/applications for any user to be able to use it (you will need administrator permissions) or to ~/.local/share/applications (where ~ means your user directory) if you just want it to be available for one user.

Source: adapted from [Canon (MG 5350) scangear doesn't appear in dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316819/canon-mg-5350-scangear-doesnt-appear-in-dash)