# How to make Ubuntu 13.04 open .py with IDLE for Python 2.7 automatically?

Tags: python, idle-python

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and python 2.7. When I click a .py file, it opens it in gedit. I want it to open in IDLE. When I right-click and choose "open with", IDLE is not in the list. I have tried several things I've read online but none have worked.

Edit: I've fixed it. I needed to add a -python2.7 when opening idle.desktop, which allowed me to open the proper file and edit the proper line.

Comment: Do you have a .desktop file for "IDLE"? In case  you need help on that you could look at [How to create a .desktop file](http://askubuntu.com/a/282187/25656)

Comment: how do I find out if I do? I'm fairly new to Ubuntu. edit: sorry, didn't see the second part.

Comment: In that case please hang around for some time. I hope someone will come along and guide you :). You could also edit your question to explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: that second thing is really gibberish to me, once again I have no idea how all this stuff works, I got Ubuntu barely two weeks ago

Comment: So explain what all you've tried so far. Or just wait for a Python expert to come along. All the best.

Comment: @lukas Since you've found a solution, please [post it as an ansswer](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). This will help others and clarify that your problem is solved (especially if you mark your own answer as accepted, which you will be able to do in 2 days).