# What does the StartupWMClass field of a .desktop file represent?

Tags: .desktop

I am working on this pre-existent **.desktop** file and I have a doubt:

The file content is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
#Icon=connect-data-space
Icon=XCloud
Categories=Utility;
Type=Application
#Exec=/usr/share/ConnectDataSpace/appl/launcher.sh
Exec=/usr/share/XCloud/appl/launcher.sh
Name[en_US]=Connect Data Space
#Name=Connect Data Space
Name=XCloud
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
StartupWMClass=ConnectDataSpace
Actions=CheckUpgrade

[Desktop Action CheckUpgrade]
Name=Verifica Aggiornamenti
#Exec=java -jar /usr/share/ConnectDataSpace/appl/lib/shellExtBridge.jar -checkupgrade
Exec=java -jar /usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/shellExtBridge.jar -checkupgrade
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

What exactly does the **StartupWMClass** field of this file represent?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Modern Linux desktop environments (Gnome 3, Ubuntu Unity, Docky) use the `WMClass` property to associate windows with the owning application. Many Java-based applications have the problem where the windows created by the application are not associated with the shortcut used to start the application (so the dock contains multiple copies of the same icon).

So the field called `StartupWMClass` is a string that defines in which class the application is grouped in the Unity Launcher at startup.

You can find out which `WM_CLASS` your window has got when you type in a terminal:

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

and then click at the window. In case of the gnome terminal the output is as follows:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"
```

So all windows with `WM_CLASS` "gnome-terminal" and "Gnome-terminal" are grouped together.

Comment: I find useful to link to official FreeDesktop specifications page, though it does not add a lot of info: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html

Comment: More to the answer: don't use quotation in the value of the desktop file.

Comment: For clarity: this setting won't have any effect on what `WM_CLASS` is, it just tells the launcher what class it should expect the launched application to have. If the application really does have that class, it will be grouped under the launcher icon made from this `.desktop` file.

Comment: Also note that this is an X11 concept. Ubuntu 22+ uses Wayland by default, which doesn't really use `WM_CLASS` so not sure this setting will have any effect.

Comment: @Tgr It has effects at least for Xampp installation

Answer (score 7):

On newer systems with Wayland, `xprop` tool won't work anymore.

If you are using GNOME Shell, you can use a built-in tool [Looking Glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass).

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `lg` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the top-right panel, select "Windows".

The WM_CLASS will be displayed under the `wmclass` key.

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

On a side note, notice that under **Kde/Kwin** and **wayland**, xprop won't work.

You'll have to use `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin queryWindowInfo` and click on the window you want to observe.

WMClass will be in the resourceClass attribute.