# Eclipse has two icons on unity launcher when I only want one

Tags: unity, eclipse

I recently upgraded to Eclipse Luna and since then I've had trouble launching it from the Unity Launcher. I've modified my old `.desktop` file located in `~/.local/share/applications`, then added it to my launcher and now it looks like this:

[image: Valid XHTML]

How can I fix this?

For reference, here's my `eclipse.desktop` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Path=/home/jinkim/eclipse
Icon=/home/jinkim/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/jinkim/eclipse/eclipse
Name=Eclipse Luna
Comment=This is an IDE
Icon=eclipse
```

Comment: slightly different symptom, same cause.

Comment: It's a slightly different problem, as I have already done `grep -rI "eclipse"` in `/usr/share/applications` and it turns up with nothing. The only eclipse-related `.desktop` file I can see is the one in my `~/.local` directory

Comment: You really must have two, calling the same application, but differently named. I'll take a look...

Comment: Could you grep -rI "eclipse" in ~/.local/share/applications? it is possible that files have slightly different names.

Comment: Yes I tried the `grep` in `~/.local/share/applications` and it turned up with the desktop file noted above. However, after searching for solutions I managed to get a working `.desktop` file. I will answer this question with what worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there a line in the `.desktop` file that I was missing. In particular, the crucial line seems to be:

```
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

More info on that here: [What represent the StartupWMClass field of a .desktop file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-represent-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file)

So, I have found what works for me below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
GenericName=Eclipse Java IDE
Comment=Eclipse Java IDE
Categories=Utility;Developer Tools;IDEs;Java;
Exec=/home/(your-username-here)/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/(your-username-here)/eclipse/icon.xpm
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-FullName=Eclipse Java IDE
```

The steps I took to get this working are:

1. Use a text editor to create `eclipse.desktop`, and paste the above into it
2. Move `eclipse.desktop` into `~/.local/share/applications`
3. Allow it to be executable: `chmod +x eclipse.desktop`
4. Double-click `eclipse.desktop` which should appear in Nautilus as `Eclipse`
5. In Unity launcher, right-click and select "Lock to Launcher"

Comment: The weird thing is that you had two (correct eclipse) icons. Usually in these cases one of them is apppearing as a question mark, that's why the StartupWMClass -thought didn't come into my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem of duplicated icon.
but in my case it was caused because I double clicked in the eclipse executable and ask unit to lock it in the launcher.  this action makes unity to create an eclipse.desktop file into ~/.local/share/applications where its "exec=" was set to java instead of eclipse executable.
After I removed the one created by unity and added my own, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you installed Eclipse and which distribution you chose, you may find the `StartupWMClass` needs a different value (Use the `xprop WM_CLASS` method described in the link in Jin's answer above).

Having built a custom Eclipse from the Platform Runtime distribution, I was getting an extra "No Entry" icon with "SWT" as its caption. Using `xprop WM_CLASS` told me the class is called "SWT", and setting `StartupWMClass=SWT` resolves the problem.