# Additional question mark icon in Launcher when launching an app, and then the original disappears

Tags: unity, launcher, okular, flatpak

I when I try to open Okular which I've installed using flatpak, I see these two icons in my launcher:

[image]

After a while the Okular icon disappears and only the question mark one remains. What could be causing this and what could be a fix?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You need to add a correct `StartupWMClass` entry to the application's `.desktop` launcher. Possible duplicate of [Eclipse has two icons on unity launcher when I only want one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527153/eclipse-has-two-icons-on-unity-launcher-when-i-only-want-one)

Comment: Seems like this is the case. Though the solution there doesn't work directly since the `.dekstop` files aren't available in the usual locations for flatpak apps. I'll try to search where it is and if it can be overridden without flatpack overwriting it when it updates the app