# Atom classic snap not showing up in search & files after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: 17.10, snap, atom

I updated my machine yesterday to Ubuntu 17.10 and suddenly I can no longer use the launcher to start Atom editor. It was installed as a snap and can be launched via the software app (it is installed) but it will not show up when doing a search . I cannot set it as a favorite either.

The version of my Atom snap is 1.21.1 (updated 10/19/2017).

```
  $ snap --version
    snap    2.28.5+17.10
    snapd   2.28.5+17.10
    series  16
    ubuntu  17.10
    kernel  4.13.0-16-generic
```

There's a [thread](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/3398) about this but I can't find/understand a solution there.

Update: I made a [bug report on the developer's github](https://github.com/snapcrafters/atom/issues/17). Atom says that they don't maintain the snaps, so it is not their issue.

Comment: Try to follow [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967409/cant-add-custom-desktop-files-to-dock-17-10) and see if it works. In the `Exec=` line try to provide the full path to the executable.

Comment: this is being discussed in the forum at
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/desktop-snaps-do-not-appear-in-the-dash-menu-on-gnome-in-17-10-final-beta/2340

Comment: @ogra 404 "The page does not exist or is private"