# How to start Atom in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, unity-dash, atom

Previously, in ubuntu 17.04, I could pin Atom to the dash, or start it from the cli using `atom .`.

After upgrading I can no longer find atom in the dash, and the cli command no longer works.

How can I start atom? And how can I add it to the dash?

Comment: See this to pin an app to the dock: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967409/cant-add-custom-desktop-files-to-dock-17-10 But you need to know the command or the path to the executable first for the `Exec=` line.

Comment: Did you upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 or did you do a fresh installation?

Comment: I upgraded from 17.04.

Comment: Have you installed atom from a packaged snap?