# Cannot add custom launcher to Ubuntu Dock ('Add to Favorites' option does not show up)

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock, favorites

I have a custom `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/home/alex/bin/idea-IC-173.4127.27/bin/idea.png
Name[en_US]=IntelliJ
Exec=/home/alex/bin/idea-IC-173.4127.27/bin/idea.sh
Name=IntelliJ
Icon=/home/alex/bin/idea-IC-173.4127.27/bin/idea.png
```

Output of `ls -lha .local/share/applications/intellij.desktop`:

```
-rwx--x--x 1 alex alex 248 Dez 30 10:54 .local/share/applications/intellij.desktop
```

Answers posted to a previous question ([How can I add custom '.desktop' application launchers to Ubuntu Dock?](https://askubuntu.com/q/967409)) don't work for me. I can find this launcher in *Activities* and I can double click on that file and IntelliJ will start. Nevertheless, I cannot add this launcher as a favorite to the dock. The option does not show up.

Comment: All of the responses here are how to _set_ the favorites. I don't see any responses about how to _add_ one without having prior knowledge of what favorites are there. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193496/add-app-to-favorites-from-command-line This question might be helpful to people in my situation.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

You should get the list of `.desktop` files associated to the apps pinned to Ubuntu dock in order, something like the following:

```
['appname-1.desktop', 'appname-2.desktop', 'appname-3.desktop', 'appname-4.desktop', 'appname-5.desktop']
```

Suppose you want to pin the app associated to the `intellij.desktop` file as the second item in the dock. In that case, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['appname-1.desktop', 'intellij.desktop', 'appname-2.desktop', 'appname-3.desktop', 'appname-4.desktop', 'appname-5.desktop']"
```

Comment: This works! But when I start the app, another app icon appears. https://imgur.com/a/8GZ7j

Comment: @kerner1000 Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/975230/480481 from step 4 onwards

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot! I got acutally two strings back from `xprop`, I used the second one (`jetbrains-idea-ce`).

Comment: It may be more user-friendly to put it this way: wherever you put a .desktop file, make it executable and trustable when clicking to open it, then right-click on the icon in the dock and add to the favourites.

Comment: @funicorn As per OP, the others methods (e.g. *Add to favourites*) mentioned in older questions are not working for them. That's why they asked a new question.

Comment: When is this supposed to start working?

Comment: @Anna If done correctly, it should start working right away. If it doesn't, try logging out and then logging in again.

Answer (score 17):

The answer from @pomsky is correct, but there is an easier way: use

```
dconf-editor
```

(install it with `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` if not installed) and navigate to

`org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`.

There it is possible to edit and rearrange the Launcher.

Answer (score 11):

This can happen when the `StartupWMClass` doesn't correspond to the WMClass of the application. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-does-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file-represent) for details on how it works and how to find the WMClass. In my case, setting the correct `StartupWMClass` in the `.desktop` file fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file was initially named `idea.desktop`

I had to rename it to `jetbrains-idea.desktop` to get this to work

I realized this since hovering over the icon on the dock shows a tooltip of `jetbrains-idea`

```
sudo mv /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop /usr/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop
```