# Firefox profiles with different icons in Ubuntu dock

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock

Ubuntu 17.10 (xorg), GNOME 3.26.2, Firefox 58.0 (64 bit).

I have a few Firefox profiles setup.  When I run each profile, I would like it to be a separate icon on the dock.  How do I make that happen?  Right now what happens is that they are all grouped in the standard Firefox icon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit profile's **.desktop** file:

- add `--class SomeClass` to the end of `Exec` key to change program's *WM_CLASS* value (see [this article](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/running.html))
- add new key `StartupWMClass=SomeClass` to the end of file (see [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-does-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file-represent) and [desktop entry specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html))

The string `SomeClass` must be the same in both changes.

Example **.desktop** file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Test
Exec=firefox -p test -no-remote --class FxTest
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/path/to/custom/icon.png
StartupWMClass=FxTest
```

**Added in 2022**
For Snapped Firefox you can try [Parallel Installs](https://snapcraft.io/docs/parallel-installs):

1. `sudo snap set system experimental.parallel-instances=true`
2. reboot
3. `sudo snap install firefox_parallel --unaliased`
4. `cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox+parallel_firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`
5. `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox+parallel_firefox.desktop`

Comment: grisfer, this answer appears to work for the question I asked, so thank you.  However.....  While I do now have distinct icons on the dock, they are all the official Firefox icon, and not the icon I specified in the desktop file.  (I realize that is not part of my original question.)

Comment: Did you add both changes (`--class SomeClass` and `StartupWMClass=SomeClass`)? If only the first, then the icons will be distinct, but with the standard image. Also, the string `SomeClass` must be the same in both changes. If the strings are different then icons will be with the standard image.

Comment: I added both, using the exact same string.  Result was it used the Firefox icon, not the icon I specified.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. It works for me (I have a custom icon).

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118613) suggests that gnome is not honoring the `--class` option

Comment: @JellicleCat Indeed, this does not work for me on Gnome 3.30. Thanks for pointing to the bugreport.

Comment: This works for me on KDE Plasma 5.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the firefox icon file.

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop \
   /usr/share/applications/firefox-dev.desktop
```

In the new file edit 4 lines, using the full path for the executable and icon.  The icon shown below is a blue colored version of the firefox icon.

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox
Icon=/opt/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
...
[Desktop Action new-window]
...
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox -new-window
...
[Desktop Action new-private-window]
...
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev/firefox -private-window
```

Then follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/990833/723997) to put the new icon file in the gnome registry.

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

Navigate to `org.gnome.shell favorite-apps` and add in your new icon

```
[ ..., 'firefox.desktop', 'firefox-dev.desktop', ... ]
```

It may necessary to log out and log back in before using the icon.