# Firefox Beta instances are shown under Firefox Stable in the dock. How do we associate the Beta instance with the Beta launcher?

Tags: firefox, .desktop, browser, ubuntu-dock, mozilla

The directory `~/.local/share/applications/` includes three files associating with different versions of Firefox, namely

---

1. Firefox - `firefox.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox
Icon=/opt/firefox/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox/firefox
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Firefox
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

2. Firefox Beta - `firefox-beta.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox Beta
Icon=/opt/firefox/firefox-beta/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox-beta/firefox
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Firefox Beta
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

3. Firefox Developer Edition - `firefox-dev.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Icon=/opt/firefox/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox-dev/firefox
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

---

### The problem:

At the moment, all Firefox Beta instances are associated with the Firefox Stable launcher icon.

### The expectation:

All Firefox Beta instances must be associated with the Firefox Beta launch icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using the `StartupWMClass=Firefox Beta` line is not enough, you need to assign a valid and distinct WM Class to the launcher accordingly first.

Change the

```
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox-beta/firefox
```

line to

```
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox-beta/firefox --class FirefoxBeta
```

and then change the

```
StartupWMClass=Firefox Beta
```

line to

```
StartupWMClass=FirefoxBeta
```

Do the same with the other one.

(adapted from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1054494/480481))

Comment: Bravo! Thank you for your assistive guidance, it worked. :-)