# 22.04 - Different icons in dock for different firefox profiles

Tags: firefox, icons

I have a "youtube" gnome application that launches a "youtube" firefox profile. It has a youtube icon so that it is recognizable in the app list. The problem is that once started, it get the firefox icons and is groupes with all other firefox windows.

I would like to keep the youtube icon and keep it separated from the "standard" firefox windows in the dock. Is it possible ?

The youtube.desktop file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Youtube
Comment=Watch videos on Youtube
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox -no-remote -P youtube https://www.youtube.com/
Icon=/home/me/.local/share/applications/youtube_logo.png
```

I've tried the "WMClasses" solutions described here : [Firefox profiles with different icons in Ubuntu dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000818/firefox-profiles-with-different-icons-in-ubuntu-dock) but it seems outdated : with firefox 100.0.2, `firefox --class test` creates a windows with `wmclass=firefox`

Comment: Case matters in linux. Try -p instead of -P as in the question you linked to.

Comment: @vanadium you mean for the profile option ? `firefox -h`  states it's `-P` not `-p` but I've tried and both works. The selection profile is fine, that's not the problem. The problem is to have 2 separate icons in the dock when using 2 profile (or when starting from a different desktop entry)

Comment: You are right, it is the big P. Changing the class should work with Firefox. Sure you made no spelling errors in the .desktop file or so?

Comment: I have the following lines modified from the code above `Exec=/usr/bin/firefox -no-remote -P youtube --class youtube https://www.youtube.com/` `StartupWMClass=youtube` and nothing is changed. Using "Looking Glass", I still see `wmclass: firefox`. I wonder if this something related to Wayland vs X11 ?

Comment: Can you test it? Switch to X11 and see if it works there.

Comment: it seems [gnome doesn't honor --class](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118613), to it firefox is firefox :/

Comment: @MoaMoaK how are you checking for wmclass?