# firefox, launch application on icon created specifically for private

Tags: firefox, dock

I'm doing a search here on the web and I can't find it.
I created a new launcher for my firefox-private, added the parameters and it's working, but when I click to run it, it's redirecting to the official icon in the dock and not to the one I create specifically for private.
is it possible to start it from the icon i created?
are pinned to my dock as favorites

[dock-firefox-icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghr0C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
today: 2022-12-13
```

download new icon: [download](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficheiro:Firefox_Focus_2021_Icon.png)

Added in 2022
For Snapped Firefox you can try Parallel Installs:

1. `$ sudo snap set system experimental.parallel-instances=true`
2. reboot
3. `$ sudo snap install firefox_parallel --unaliased`
4. `$ sudo nano /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox+parallel_firefox.desktop`
5. locate, comment and add. to save `ctrl + x` > `y` > `enter`

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
# Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox+parallel_firefox.desktop /snap/bin/firefox_parallel %u
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox+parallel_firefox.desktop /snap/bin/firefox_parallel %u --private-window
...
#Icon=/snap/firefox_parallel/2154/default256.png
Icon=/path/download/new/firefox/icon.png
...
```

font: [Firefox profiles with different icons in Ubuntu dock](https://askubuntu.com/a/1054494/1657032)

result: [github](https://gist.github.com/WellingtonFonseca/818786228e1e13d153e631a6d2a6809b)