# How to customize Ubuntu Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock

How can I customize Ubuntu Dock via terminal. I would like to add Chrome and remove Amazon.

[image: Ubuntu 18 side bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on the application icon you want to remove and select "*Remove from Favourites*". Similarly right click on an application icon you want to add when the application is running and select "*Add to Favourites*".

If you *really* want to use Terminal to achieve your goal, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/992351/480481).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works! my other concern is on other user my customized side bar is not applied.

Comment: How can i customized it on pxe boot?

Comment: @crltzn Sorry, no idea :(