# How to change show application button place

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, macosx, dash-to-dock

How can I change "show applications" button place? I want to change it to second place.

My dock sequence: {
      1 Show Applications Button 
      2 Files 
      3 Terminal 
      4 Google Chrome Developer 
      5 Thunderbird Mail 
      6 Visual Studio Code Insiders 
      7 All Other Libre Office Programs 
      ... 
      8 Trash Can

}

I want to make: {
      2 Files 
      1 Show Applications Button 
      3 Terminal 
      4 Google Chrome Developer 
      5 Thunderbird Mail 
      6 Visual Studio Code Insiders 
      7 All Other Libre Office Programs 
      ... 
      8 Trash Can

}

[Image of "Dock in macOS", "Dash in Ubuntu", "Taskbar in Windows".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cnGc.png)

In short, I want it to be like macOS

## Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nmath I just uploaded 1 image and I asked realy clearly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add programs to the Unity Launcher or Ubuntu Dock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224004/how-to-add-programs-to-the-unity-launcher-or-ubuntu-dock) or [How to customize Ubuntu Dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023484/how-to-customize-ubuntu-dock) or [What docks are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8865/what-docks-are-available) - The image looks like it comes from MacOS - but you have labeled them as "Dash in Ubuntu" and "Taskbar in Windows".

Comment: You can add links like this `[name](http://url)`

Comment: And embed images like this `![alttext](http://url)`