# Applications added to Ubuntu Dock get reset on reboot in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

In Ubuntu 18.04, I have added some applications/softwares as "**Add to Favorites**" to Dock. On reboot, it got resets, and I need to do the same again.

- changes happens to manually added ones. For example, chrome, gedit etc.
- I have removed Thunderbird,Amazon from dock, but, they doesn't come back.

[image]
Now I have added chrome to dock, but on reboot it shows only apps that were left to the chrome.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you notice this with only some specific applications or *all* the manually added ones get reset after reboot?

Comment: I have edited question with screen shot

Comment: What happens if you add it [in this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990833/cannot-add-custom-launcher-to-dock-add-to-favorites)?

Comment: I have tried through terminal and dconf methods. But, it continues to be the same.