# Unable to add latest Firefox browser to Favorites on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, favorites

I have downloaded the latest Firefox tar.bz2 file and extracted in **home** directory, I added it in **Favorites**. 
But when I launch it shows the older version.

How can I add the latest version in Favorites to launch it directly from the dock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mine which is working fine on Ubuntu 18.04 :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer 
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/home/sebastien/firefox-dev/firefox %u
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/sebastien/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
StartupNotify=true
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I was missing %u in Exec as well as : 
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition, 
StartupNotify=true

Answer (score 5):

For who is having trouble with Firefox Developer Edition, according to this https://askubuntu.com/a/1201328, you have to set the correct `StartupWMClass` in the `.desktop` file. My current Firefox Developer version is 98.0b3 and the value for `StartupWMClass` is `firefox-aurora`

```
StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora
```

Note: shouldn't add quotation in the value of the desktop file

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Copy the .desktop file of your new firefox version to .local/share/applications. This will override your system-wide installed firefox.desktop file. Next time you launch firefox, your new firefox.desktop will be in effect. After firefox has loaded, pin it to the dash.

If still your old firefox version is loaded, then probably the .desktop file, on its `Exec=` line, just calls "firefox" rather than the specific executable of your new version.

If the .tar.gz of your new firefox version does not contain a .desktop file, then copy your system wide firefox.desktop from /usr/share/applications to .local/share/applications.

In both cases, edit the local copy, and change the `Exec=` line to reflect the actual file path of the executable of your new version. This file path will depend on where you installed this version.

Comment: Hi Vanadium, Thanks for your help. Firstly I added the firefox.desktop file located in /usr/share/applications, It didn't work. Then I added the firefox.desktop in .local/share/applications, It worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For me changing the `NoDisplay` from `true` to `false` helped in the file `~/.local/share/applications`
i.e
`NoDisplay=false`

I also added `Icon`, `Terminal`, `StartupNotify`, `StartupWMClass`

Here is how the file looks now

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
NoDisplay=false
Exec=/home/amit/firefox/firefox-bin %u
Name=Firefox
Comment=Custom definition for Firefox
StartupWMClass=Firefox
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/amit/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
```