# Add app to favorites from command line

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, favorites

I am aware that you can right-click on an application and choose "Add to Favorites". I am trying to add it to the favorites section without using the GUI at all. Everything needs to be done in the terminal or a script.

Anyone have any ideas?

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/990833/480481). That is for SETTING the favorites, not ADDING to the favorites. When you right click on an application and choose "Add to Favorites", that must run a script somewhere that takes an input of the application name. What I'm asking is, where is that script or how can I replicate it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, as an end-user you can only "read" and "write" (also reset) the array that dictates the list of favourite apps by using `dconf`/`gsettings`. For example, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/992351/480481), you can get the value by running

```bash
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

and write a new value by a suitable `gsettings set` command. There is no straightforward way to append to the array, you can only overwrite.

But you can combine these two and have a custom command. You need to know the name of the `.desktop` launcher associated to the application you want to add to the favourites first. Let's say it is `appname.desktop`. Then you can run the following to add the application associated to `appname.desktop` to the favourites:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "$(gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps | sed s/.$//), 'appname.desktop']"
```

Comment: Life saver, thank you! I'm not as familiar with all the available commands within Ubuntu as I'd like to be, and this is incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The path for `dconf` is: `/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`. For example

```
dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
```

Which for me produces

```
['org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'vivaldi-stable.desktop', 'steam.desktop']
```

So in theory you could use `dconf write` to adjust these values

Comment: Welcome! If you can, complete the answer with an example of configuration, that way you will get upvoted and accepted

Comment: That is setting the favorite apps, not adding to them.

Comment: my ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have `/org`...