# add app to favorites from command line KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I have created a .desktop for some applications in KDE inside  `.local/share/applications`, I would like to know if it is possible to add them to 'favorites' in the application launcher from the terminal, as I create the .desktop from a script, similar to this question [Add app to favorites from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193496/add-app-to-favorites-from-command-line) but for KDE

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The favorites are stored by `kactivitymanagerd` service](https://github.com/KDE/kactivitymanagerd/blob/73250bc9a140204c587f823d7b7f8ffd665dd350/src/common/dbus/org.kde.ActivityManager.ResourcesLinking.xml#L5). We can have the script talk to the service:

```bash
# <Have your script create the .desktop file>
DESKTOP_FILE_NAME=org.kde.dolphin.desktop # Specify the name of the file

# Add to application launcher favorites
if pgrep -cfU $UID '^/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kactivitymanagerd$' > /dev/null; then
  # The service is running so ask it to add the new favorite
  # in the same way plasmashell would ask it to.
  dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.kde.ActivityManager /ActivityManager/Resources/Linking org.kde.ActivityManager.ResourcesLinking.LinkResourceToActivity string:org.kde.plasma.favorites.applications string:applications:"$DESKTOP_FILE_NAME" string::any
  # Refresh the display
  kquitapp5 plasmashell &> /dev/null
  kstart5 plasmashell  &> /dev/null
else
  # The service is not running, so modify the favorites database.
  echo "INSERT INTO ResourceLink(usedActivity,initiatingAgent,targettedResource) VALUES (':global','org.kde.plasma.favorites.applications','applications:$DESKTOP_FILE_NAME');" | sqlite3 ~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd/resources/database
fi
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for your answer, could you clarify a little bit better the 'script interact'? as I thought that kactivitymanagerd was a file but it is a folder in $HOME/.local/share  thanks in advance

Comment: @otaolafr The 'script interact' doesn't mean much. It's just a random sentence I used for the introduction. I changed it to "have the script talk to the service". kactivitymanagerd is indeed an executable file at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kactivitymanagerd` but it ***stores its data*** in the folder at `~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd`. It's just like how konsole is an executable file at `/usr/bin/konsole` but stores its files in the folder at `~/.local/share/konsole`