# Unable to dock TeamViewer in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock, teamviewer

In Ubuntu 18.04, I'm not able to dock TeamViewer. Even if I right click on the TeamViewer icon when opened, I can't see an option to make it favorite. How can I dock the teamviewer here permanently?

[image: Dock]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Cannot add custom launcher to Ubuntu Dock (Add to Favorites)](https://askubuntu.com/q/990833/775359) as suggested by [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky), the following worked.

Get a list of existing favorites

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps

['org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop', 'spacefm.desktop', 'notepad-plus-plus_notepad-plus-plus.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop', 'gnome-system-monitor_gnome-system-monitor.desktop', 'teams.desktop']
```

Locate where the desktop files are stored using one the listed favorites

```
$ locate org.gnome.Terminal.desktop

/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop
```

Search for desktop file of teamviewer at that lcoation

```
$ ls /usr/share/applications | grep teamviewer

com.teamviewer.TeamViewer.desktop
```

Add teamviewer desktop file to list of favorites

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop', 'spacefm.desktop', 'notepad-plus-plus_notepad-plus-plus.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop', 'gnome-system-monitor_gnome-system-monitor.desktop', 'teams.desktop', 'com.teamviewer.TeamViewer.desktop']"
```