# Postman.desktop not showing up in GNOME Dash in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: .desktop, gnome-shell

I've followed documentation provided by GNOME [Desktop files: putting your application in the desktop menus](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)
 and created an entry `postman.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Postman
Exec=/opt/Postman/Postman
Icon=/opt/Postman/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

And my postman installation is in `/opt/Postman`. But it's not showing up in my Ubuntu 17.10 Dash. The same kind of configuration worked for PyCharm.

Comment: Yeah. I'm able to run it from terminal. postman.desktop also runs if i double click on it. But it's not showing up in Gnome launcher

Comment: Yeah. If i open postman and click on activities it's showing up. But the shortcut is not appearing in gnome dash/launcher (i don't know what to call it.)

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967409/cant-add-custom-desktop-files-to-dock-17-10

Comment: Thanks for the link, i verified my .desktop file. My problem is little different here. I'm able to add it to favourites but it's not showing up in all applications screen. I did same kind of config for PyCharm. It immediately appeared in all applications but postman didn't.

Answer (score 4):

I see you're following the gnome desktop file instructions. Try following the Postman Installation documentation [here](https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604/?utm_source=hootsuite&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=)

When I tried installing Postman, the icon only showed up in my gnome application menu after I ran `sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman` from the instructions.

EDIT: Starting with version 6.1.3, run `sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/app/Postman /usr/bin/postman` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to fix the link? I can't see anything in the Postman doc related to the integration in Ubuntu desktop environment.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the link. Here it is just in case it still doesn’t work: https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604/?utm_source=hootsuite&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=

Comment: Thanks. This `sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman` worked for me on version Postman v8.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I think is just to install Postman from Snap store:

```
sudo snap install postman
```

It will appear in Dash and also could add to Favorites

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the previous answer because I don't have enough reputation. Starting with version `6.1.3`, need to run `sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/app/Postman /usr/bin/postman` instead.

Comment: You can suggest an edit to the post adding this information

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Open Terminal

Step 2 : cd /usr/share/applications/

Step 3 : sudo nano postman.desktop
(Enter your password and a file will be opened for you)

Step 4 : Paste Following code line...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Postman
Icon=/opt/Postman/app/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Exec=/opt/Postman/Postman
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Postman
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

NOTE : Postman folder should place in /opt directory and please check above Icon and Exec path same as yours If not change it as your way.