# Cannot lock Mellow Player application to favourites bar

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-dock, favorites

I have downloaded Mellow Player as an AppImage. I can run this with no problems from the terminal, however I would like to lock this to the Favourites panel.

I have tried creating a `mellow-player.desktop` file, this again works at opening Mellow Player but there is still no option to add to favourites. This is the `.desktop` file I created:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/Desktop/MellowPlayer-x86_64.AppImage
Name=mellow-player
```

Comment: have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/990833/cannot-add-custom-launcher-to-dock-add-to-favorites

Comment: thanks for the replies  @pomsky (and kerner). I have tried both of these links and successfully managed to get the favourite panel working for the chrome example. However it still doesn't work for mellow player: it does not appear in the search in activities aswell.

Comment: The `Exec=` line seems to be wrong. Try `/home/YOUR-USERNAME/Desktop/MellowPlayer-x86_64.AppImage`.

Comment: Put the desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` and it should appear in the applications overview and from there you should be able to add it to the favorites bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Exec=` line seems to be wrong. Change it to

```
Exec=/home/YOUR-USERNAME/Desktop/MellowPlayer-x86_64.AppImage
```

(Put your username in place of `YOUR-USERNAME`)

Then follow this Q&A: [Can't add Custom .desktop files to dock 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967409/cant-add-custom-desktop-files-to-dock-17-10)