# 18.04 pin and unpin entries in dock

Tags: 18.04, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I want to pin and unpin entries in the dock in 18.04 desktop. I have checked out `gsettings` and have not found how to do this. Is `gsettings` even the right tool for this? Any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot add custom launcher to Dock (\*Add to Favorites\*)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990833/cannot-add-custom-launcher-to-dock-add-to-favorites) -- this is the `gsettings` way you're looking for, but the simplest way is right-click and "add/remove to/from favourites" or simply drag-and-drop (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967409/cant-add-custom-desktop-files-to-ubuntu-dock)).

Comment: @pomsky The answer to that question only concerns rearranging existing entries in the dock, not adding new entries or removing entries. I know how to do this graphically. I am developing scripts to create customized Ubuntu systems and want to include dock customization.

Comment: No, you didn't read it carefully. It shows, as an example, how the app associated to the `intellij.desktop` launcher, **which was not there previously**, was added *as the second item* to the dock.

Comment: The linked answer is correct. `gsettings` is the right tool and adding entries is done via modifying the existing list, or providing a new list altogether. Of course, you could write it in Python so that managing the list is easier, but on the very basic level the linked answer is the way to go.