# Adding an icon for Spyder in Favourites bar in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock, spyder

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 and Anaconda (with Python 3.7) in my laptop, and I want to set up a launcher icon for the Spyder IDE in the Favourites bar - something I've done many times in the past couple of years when running Ubuntu 16.

I can successfully launch Spyder from the Terminal and it seems to be working fine, but when I run it from the terminal and right-click the icon, it does not give me an option for adding it to Favorites.

[Strangely, searching for an application named "spyder" returns no results; not sure if this might be related, but...]

I understand I can manually add an icon for it by creating a `.desktop` file, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967409/cant-add-custom-desktop-files-to-ubuntu-dock) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990833/cannot-add-custom-launcher-to-dock-add-to-favorites), and adding it to `/usr/share/applications`, as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles). For example, I have tried using the following `spyder.desktop` file (available in the [Spyder Github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/tree/master/scripts)):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Spyder
GenericName=Spyder
Comment=The Scientific Python Development Environment
Icon=spyder
TryExec=spyder
Exec=spyder %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/x-python;
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
Keywords=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
StartupNotify=true
X-AppStream-Ignore=True
StartupWMClass=Spyder
```

However, even after creating this file, Spyder still does not show up in Applications. And if I try to run this file, I get a fairly generic

> "There was an error launching the application"

message.

Is this a known issue with Spyder and/or Ubuntu 18? Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, at which directory did you put the `.desktop` file?

Comment: I added it to `/usr/share/applications` - was that the right place?

Comment: Please type this command in the terminal: `whereis spyder` and post the output

Comment: @koni_raid The output is `spyder: /home/hirono/anaconda3/bin/spyder`

Comment: @Kulfy The .desktop file has executable permissions. However, I don't understand where I have to add the absolute path in the .desktop file; could you please help me with that?

Comment: @fabio_hirono What Kulfy meant is change the `Exec=spyder %F` line to `Exec=/home/hirono/anaconda3/bin/spyder %F`. Do the same with `TryExec` line too.

Comment: @pomsky Thanks for the explanation. Funny thing: if I add the absolute path to either `Exec` or `TryExec` (but not both), I still get the error message. By adding it to both, I can then run the `.desktop` file successfully and get Spyder to open. I can now find Spyder in Applications and open it from there, but it doesn't display an icon on the Favourites bar while running!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error message *"There was an error launching the application"* suggests, there is some sort of error in `spyder.desktop`. Fields like `Exec` and `TryExec` require the **absolute path** of the executable file, therefore the values for `Exec` and `TryExec` must be `/home/hirono/anaconda3/bin/spyder`. Same goes for Icon. It seems like you haven't given even the extension for the icon image. Value must be like `/home/hirono/path-to-icon/icon.png`.

Also, double check the permissions of `spyder.desktop` and `/home/hirono/anaconda3/bin/spyder`. They both must be executable.

Comment: Awesome! Adding the absolute paths and ensuring the permissions sorted the problem with the `.desktop` file, and adding a path to the icon (I used `/home/hirono/anaconda3/share/icons/spyder3.png` ) gave me a nice icon to add and display in my Favourites :) many thanks to all that helped!

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by Kulfy worked for me. Just as a note for others who are having this issue, I was skeptical that adding the absolute path was the fix I needed since calling spyder from the terminal worked fine and calling

spyder.desktop->

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Spyder
GenericName=Spyder
Comment=The Scientific Python Development Environment
Icon=spyder
TryExec=spyder
Exec=spyder %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/x-python;
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
Keywords=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
StartupNotify=true
X-AppStream-Ignore=True
StartupWMClass=Spyder
```

as

```
gtk-launch spyder.desktop
```

would also launch spyder correctly. I don't know why it matters, but definitely use the abs path for applications not installed via terminal apt-get that have this issue.

after making changes to the <application>.desktop file alt-F2->r->enter to reload profile instead of logging out/ back in.