# Why can't I add some applications to favourites?

Tags: gnome-shell, favorites

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 with GNOME and 'Dash to Panel'. I don't understand why I can make some opened apps favourites (with right click) but not others (like caffeine). Why?

Comment: You can do it using `gsettings` or `dconf`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/990833/cannot-add-custom-launcher-to-dock-add-to-favorites

Comment: If you disable the extension, log out and back in, does it work then? If yes, then culprit is in the extension you use. If not, we need to look further. Other apps that do not work?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/973877/607831 , note discussion of 'StartupWMClass'.

Comment: I think you need to create a .desktop file to do that