# Create a shortcut to a virtual enviroment

Tags: shortcuts, virtualenv, spyder

I have installed Spyder Python IDE in a virtual environment.
For this purpose I used the following command:

```
python3 -m venv spyder-env
source spyder-env/bin/activate
```

I have to switch to the virtual environment and then type spyder.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
Can I create a bash command as a shortcut and then create a desktop icon to directly open it in order to save time?

Comment: If you are already using a bash shell by default, try `source /home/<your_username>/spyder-env/bin/activate; spyder`. If you are using the Ubuntu default dash (not bash) shell, there's one extra step to use bash: try `/bin/bash -c "source /home/<your_username>/spyder-env/bin/activate; spyder"`. Bash is required to use 'source', which dash lacks.

Answer (score 2):

I reach to this question with a similar problem, but in my case my virtual environment was created on conda...
I am sharing the solution for the desktop icon I found for conda environment (I named  the environment 'spyder'), for someone else struggling with a similar problem...:

```
Name=Spyder5
Comment=spyder inside virtual environment
Exec=bash -i -c "conda activate spyder; python -m spyder.app.start"
Icon=/home/<username>/anaconda3/envs/spyder/share/icons/spyder.png
Type=Application
Terminal=true
```

Inside `spyder.desktop` file created as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/967443/1188532).
The `bash -i -c`, and the `;` mentioned by the [user5357633](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) in the comment above directed me to the solution.