# Some .desktop files not working anymore in 19.04

Tags: gnome, firefox, .desktop, 19.04

I use several instances of Firefox, that I usually launch from various launchers.

For example, I have a `firefox-test.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`, that contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox-Test
StartupWMClass=firetest
Exec=firefox --new-instance --no-remote -P Test --class firetest %u
Icon=firefox-developer-icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Keywords=web;browser;internet;pentest;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
```

It worked for ages, in many DE, including GNOME in 18.04.

But, in 19.04, clicking on my launchers does nothing.

On the other hand, the commands works from the terminal:

```
firefox --new-instance --no-remote -P Test --class firetest
```

Is this a bug? Or an expected change?

Comment: What is the purpose of `--class`?

Comment: @DKBose Ideally that would let you set custom WMClass and use it for the [StartupWMClass entry](https://askubuntu.com/q/367396/480481).

Comment: @pomsky but will it work in the `Exec=` line the way OP has it? `man Firefox` (19.04) doesn't list it as an option.

Comment: @DKBose It's *not* a feature of Firefox, it should ideally work with Firefox and other GTK applications. Not sure it works in 19.04, but works fine for me with Firefox on 18.04.

Comment: @pomsky but do you use it in the `Exec=` line?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, same as OP. Without this hack, all Firefox windows from different profiles would get merged into a single icon in the dock

Comment: @pomsky that's neat!

Comment: Try right-clicking on the .desktop file and click Allow Launching; this worked for me in 19.04

Comment: That's weird, because I don't have such an option.

Comment: Really? Have you made any tweaks? I see that option in Ubuntu 19.04 GNOME

Comment: Or try opening Nautilus, going to /usr/share/applications, and copy a file from there to your desktop. Does that work? Sorry I’m kind of new to Ubuntu myself.

Comment: No tweaks. I have never seen this option. It means it's handled by Nautilus, that somehow change gnome-shell settings. I don't know what it is.

Comment: Still not. Anyway, it's not supposed to work that way. Launchers have always been read from the ~/.local/share/applications folder. They are found, because they are displayed by the shell, it's just that it may not respect all settings.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IhAV4Rz.png

Comment: On what icon is it? Not a Firefox launcher. These options (move, rename, etc.) are not standard. Again, I have been using Gnome 3 for almost 10 years and never 1) saw this option, 2) needed to do anything to make a menu entry work. Add the desktop file in the proper folder and it should just work.

Comment: Actually, it is from a Firefox Nightly .desktop file which I created with the same options as you. Ubuntu 19.04 w/ Gnome Shell 3.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case some has the same issue, it just does not work when you have an extension like [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) with the **workspace isolation** setting enabled or [Workspace Isolated Dash](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/887/workspace-isolated-dash/).

I don't know what the issue but in that case launching new Firefox instances is not supported.

Switching back to the standard Dash or disabling any dock workspace isolation solves the issue.

I also opened an [issue in Gnome Shell](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1752#note_618996).