# How to show dot symbol under the icon of the opened application when searching it using super key

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, search, activities-overview

Recently, I have created a `.desktop` file of Firefox application. When I run Firefox, I want to have a dot symbol under the icon of the Firefox when searching it using <kbd>super</kbd> key in GNOME just like we get on the default running application.

Comment: You will have the dot only when the application is already running.

Comment: @AnkitRajDeo I think that is the default behaviour rite? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A47U.jpg

Comment: @vanadium yes, you are right. But, it is only happening when application is installed through package manager. In case of some application, i have to create desktop file of that application so that i can open it through search. If that application is running, how can i make orange dot appear under the running application icon.

Comment: Should be there automatically on the icon representing your program. Difficult to help if you do not explain your case in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you don't have a [correct `StartupWMClass` entry](https://askubuntu.com/q/367396/480481) in your manually created `.desktop` launcher for the application. To add one, follow the steps below.

1. Launch Firefox application in question.
2. Run `xprop WM_CLASS` in a Terminal window. The cursor should turn into a crosshair.
3. Place the cursor over the opened Firefox window and click. You should get a `WM_CLASS` string for the application in Terminal.
4. Open the manually created `.desktop` file in a text editor and add (or modify) the following line

   ```
   StartupWMClass=OBTAINED-VALUE
   ```

   In place of `OBTAINED-VALUE` put a value you got from step 3 without any quotes.
5. Save the `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on  "Use built in theme". It will show the dots

[image]