# Synchronise icons between .desktop and dock

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I created a custom .desktop entry in my home directory
`~/.local/share/applications/startMyApp.desktop`
I created it so that it would use an xterm instead of gnome-terminal. I want it to have a different look in the dock from my gnome-terminals that I use interactively.

The `startMyApp.desktop` looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyScript
Terminal=false
Exec=xterm -e myScript.sh
Icon=myIcon.png
```

I have created an icon file in `~/.icons/myIcon.png`

The icon appears correctly in the default file browser. When opened from a file browser, it executes the script in an xterm as expected, however, the icon in the dock appears as some other generic xterm icon. Where does that icon comes from? Is it embedded in the binary?

How can I change this?  I want the icon in the dock to appear that same as the one specified in the `.desktop` file.  Applications bundled with Ubuntu have the same icon in the dock when launched (aside from the red dots indicating how many windows are open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a proper [`StartupWMClass` entry](https://askubuntu.com/q/367396/480481) to your `.desktop` file. To do this follow the steps below.

1. Launch the application in question.
2. Launch a separate Terminal window and run `xprop WM_CLASS`.
3. Place the cursor over the opened application window in question. The cursor should turn into a crosshair by now. Click. You should get a `WM_CLASS` string for the application in the Terminal window.
4. In the `.desktop` file add the following line

   ```
   StartupWMClass=OBTAINED-VALUE
   ```

   In place of `OBTAINED-VALUE` put a value you got from step 3 without any quotes.

---

**[Update from the OP:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245812/synchronise-icons-between-desktop-and-dock/1245816#comment2100823_1245816)**

> also it seems I needed to provide a name for the xterm instance. The exec line now looks like `xterm -name myApp -e myScript.sh`

Comment: Thanks!  A couple things. the full path did not help and was not necessary, ~/.icons is a standard directory to search for single user use, also it seems I needed to provide a name for the xterm instance. The exec line now looks like  xterm -name myApp -e myScript.sh

Comment: @jct70 Thanks for the feedback, I removed the redundant first part while expanding the second part and also appended your suggestion to the answer.