# Changing default "Open With" to a console based application

Tags: 13.10, default-programs

I have a chess program that runs from the command line by doing "scid".

I want to be able to open .pgn files automatically with scid. However, when I right click on a .pgn file and go to "Open with", I can't find scid.

How do I go about changing the default .pgn program opener to scid?

I use Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a own desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. The easiest way is to copy an existing file. Open the file with root permission in your preferred editor (gedit/nano/...) and adapt the fields.
Important is the `Exec` line. Here goes the command to be executed, where `%f` represents the file to be opened.

Comment: I did that. However, it seems to be slower than when opened by writing "scid".

Comment: I don't think there's a possibility to fix this.

Comment: It seems to be better now. I'll accept your answer. However, i copied from .local/share/applications and not /usr. Perhaps you should edit your post. I'll leave this [link here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application) as well, it helped me.

Comment: Actually, now my engine is not working. It says "Unable to execute "stockfish": no such file or directory". I went to my definition and they're good. It works when i run "scid" from the console.

Comment: what happens if you change the Exec parameter to `gnome-terminal -c "<scid command>"`?