# Trouble Creating a simple script

Tags: scripts

I just wanted to create a script that opens Teamspeak. I was on here before about that, but I thought it would be more simple by just creating a script.

I wanted to make a script to launch the script that opens Teamspeak.

So I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /home/austin/Programs/Teamspeak/launch(what I renamed the file to for ease).sh
```

I named this Teamspeak.sh and it didn't work. The thing that is frustrating is that it works if I go into terminal on the Desktop and type

```
./Teamspeak.sh
```

it works!

How can I get this to work by just double-clicking it?

Comment: Just curious as to why your creating a script to launch another script. Why not just launch your first 'launch.sh'?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/q/281293/158442. You can create a . desktop file with `Terminal=true`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're "double clicking" on it but if it's in Nautilus there is a setting in preferences about how to handle executable files.  It's on the "Behavior" tab of the preferences dialog.

Speaking of executable, you did `chmod` to make your script executable right?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If you could expand on your answer further (i.e. right click on file, select make executable, etc.) it would really improve your answer screen shots might be helpful as well. For future reference try to not ask a separate question in answers, and instead post additional questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, right-click `Teamspeak.sh` on your desktop. Click `Properties`. Go to `Permissions` tab, and tick the `Execute` option at the bottom. Click OK, and now try double-clicking it.

You may have to use `dconf-editor` if it doesn't ask you if you want to run, or launch it immediately.

If you don't have `dconf-editor` you can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then type `dconf-editor` into your terminal to open it.

Navigate to `org ➤ gnome ➤ nautilus ➤ preferences`
and look for `executable-text-activation`

Click the option next to it and choose whether you want to `launch` or `ask`

Close `dconf-editor` and now double-click it.

If you chose `launch` it'll run your script the same as if it were a program.
If you chose `ask` it'll prompt you with the options to <kbd>Run in Terminal</kbd>, <kbd>Display</kbd>, <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, or <kbd>Run</kbd>