# Moving applications from unity launcher to docky

Tags: unity, docky

I have just installed `docky` with mac style and I really like it! but it seems that there is no way to drag and drop existing application icons from unity launcher to the docky.

Foe example I want to add the `Workspace Switcher` to docky...how can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK you can't drag anything **off** the launcher. You'll need to add a separate docklet. Here, BTW google is your friend. http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=WorkspaceSwitcher_Docklet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't drag it.

1. Open the program, with the launcher.
2. Then the icon should appear in docky?
3. Right click on the icon in the dock, and chose pin to dock. Even when you close it, it will still be there.

For other things, you could create a custom `.desktop` file with the command `xdotool key Super+S`.

Then you can drag that from where you saved it to docky.

Comment: Doubt that'll be possible with the workplace switcher...

Comment: No, but you could create a custom .desktop file with the command `xdotool key Super+S`

Comment: Thanks but it works for most applications but applications which are being launched from terminal (e.g. I want to add Android Studio also in the docky but when I launch it, it doesn't go in docky anyway).

Comment: Yeah, you need to create a .desktop file: http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application