# Application not found via the "Search your computer and online resources" Ubuntu Button

Tags: software-installation

*Ubuntu Software Center* says I have installed *Padre*. Green checkmark next to **Installed**. And over on the right it has a **Remove** button. But if I click on the top left corner icon and then type "Padre" I only get **Reference**, **Weather** and **More Suggestions**  entries. No application to launch.

It also does not show up if I right click on that top-left-corner button and look for it in the list of applications icons.

But the software did install. "which padre" in a terminal window shows "/usr/bin/padre". And "padre &" in a terminal window brings up the application.

Is this a bug or a feature? Do you have to do additional work to get a program like Padre (a Perl IDE) to show up in search, or is it just a glitch in the system? On a menu-based system like KDE or Xfce there would automatically be a new item in the menu for Padre. Is this not the case for Ubuntu Unity (not menu since there is none, but searchable)?

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking the reason, or are you asking how to create a launcher to show up in that menu?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Is this a bug or a feature? Should I expect Padre to be available from typing into the search task or is just installing it not enough?

Comment: Ok now it's clear. There should be a desktop file like `/usr/share/applications/padre.desktop` or something similar. If it's there, but the program does not appear in searches, we can say it's a bug.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto There doesn't appear to be an entry for Padre in /usr/share/applications. So I guess the problem is with Padre installation - they aren't Unity aware. With one exception the other desktops do add it to their menu, although all but one stuck it in "Other" instead of "Development" and several listed it multiple times in the menu. But I guess they get their information from a different place than Unity.

Comment: Well, that's weird because they shouldn't. AFAIK all freedesktop-complaint DEs get their information from `/usr/share/applications`...

Answer (score 1):

For lightdm/unity once you bring the application through terminal an icon should appear in that launch bar on the left.  Right click it and select pin/add to launch bar. There should be something similar in KDE. Yeah some apps just don't show up in search I guess , but it's mostly seems to be common in command line apps.

Comment: As for whether that's a bug ir feature , we'd have to ask the developers