# create application shortcut on the desktop

Tags: unity

I tried to create an application shortcut to my desktop.
I am unable to move the icon to the desktop like windows does.
Do I need do code or configure to have my application on the desktop?

Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

Iccsi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a .desktop file for a new application](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)