# Creating a shorcut for application

Tags: unity, qt-creator

I have two versions of qtcreator: first is installed by apt and binary is located in `/usr/bin/`. Second is installed in a custom location (I used a bundle from qt website). I run second version from terminal and then I choose option **Lock to Launcher** for qt icon.  When I close qtcreator and launch again using that icon I get qtcreator  from `/usr/bin`. Why ? How to fix it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a .desktop file for a new application](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the `qtcreator` launcher to point to the right location you can copy the `.desktop` file of the version installed by apt-get in your `$XDG_DATA_HOME` folder (default is `~/.local/share`)

1. Open a terminal and copy the `/usr/share/applications/qtcreator.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications` :

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/qtcreator.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Edit the `Exec=` command to use your custom location:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Exec=<path_to_your_custom_location>/qtcreator %F
   Icon=QtProject-qtcreator
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Name=Qt Creator
   GenericName=Integrated Development Environment
   MimeType=text/x-c++src;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-xsrc;application/x-designer;application/vnd.nokia.qt.qmakeprofile;application/vnd.nokia.xml.qt.resource;
   Categories=Qt;Development;IDE;
   InitialPreference=9
   ```
3. Now if you lock this new `.desktop` file in your Unity Launcher it should start the right version.

Reference: http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: It works only if I modify a file which is located in /usr/share/applications

Comment: @Irbis: you have to unlock qtcreator from the launcher and start the custom `.dekstop` one from nautilus. Ensure that the custom one has the +x permission. Lock it to the launcher and it should always use the custom location

Comment: @Irbis: Or simpler, open it with the Dash. it should use the right version