# How to install Acrobat professional 8 using wine in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wine

I have installed wine1.6 in the ubuntu 12.04 and tried to install Acrobat professional 8 using wine1.6. At the near completion of installation process, installation process gets aborted and it says setup interrupted.
Does wine1.6 support Acrobat Professional 8? Please help.

Comment: have you had a look here: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=7160&iTestingId=11382

Answer (score 2):

**1. WINE WAY**

First of all, I would update wine to newer version...but that might not be necessary.

1. You need Windows (at least in VM)
2. running copy of Adobe Pro 8 on that copy of windows (That's because there is some bug, which prevents wine to copy files to desired directory and you need to do it manually)

You need to copy a few registry entries from there for Acrobat to work.
        `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> Software -> Adobe`
        Right click on the Adobe folder and select `Export`, and name this file `acrobat.reg`.
If you did not configure wine already, Run the following to create your own .wine folder.

`winecfg` (**make sure to run winecfg from the command line if you make any changes or updates to wine**)

The Windows regedit export file you just created, "acrobat.reg", is a native windows app and has a few Windows based dependencies. You need to use winetricks from the command line to install these. Execute the following (or use GUI, whatever suits you more):

```
winetricks msxml6
winetricks gdiplus
winetricks gecko
winetricks vcrun2005
winetricks vcrun2008
winetricks msxml3
winetricks atmlib
```

Copy the following files from the Windows installation into the .wine directory on Linux.

```
C\Program Files\Adobe\ ----> $HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe
C\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe ----> $HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Common Files/Adobe
C\Documents and Settings\$USER\Application Data\Adobe ----> $HOME/.wine/drive_c/users/$USER/Applications Data/Adobe
C\windows\system32\odbcint.dll ----> $HOME/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/odbcint.dll
```

Once that's done, copy over your `acrobat.reg` file from your Windows machine to your home directory and execute the command below.

`wine regedit acrobat.reg`

That will import the registry entries into the wine registry.

To test it out, go to go to `Home -> .wine -> drive_c -> Program Files -> Adobe ->Acrobat` with your favorite shell and right click on the `Acrobat.exe` and select "Open with Wine".

**There is also way with patching wine source, so it bypasses that bug with copying problem, but I guess this might be easier!**

**I've made version 10 working with similar steps**

---

**2. VB SEAMLESS MODE WAY**

- Install VB with extensions (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Install Windows on it (I have used `Tiny XP rev 11` because it runs on 100 mb of RAM + it's fast and we don't want windows to take more... quick google search should do)
- Install Guest Additions (So we can make shared folder (etc.) work)
- If you are not able to get your resolution higher even after installing Guest Additions try switching between `full screen` <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, `seamless mode` <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and `Auto resize` <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> - did the trick for me
- install Adobe Acrobat Pro as you would normally do on Windows
- set windows task bar to `auto hide`, after that go to `Machine -> Settings -> General -> Advanced` and check `Show Mini Toolbar in Seamless Mode`.
- Unmount `Guest Additions` as it would cause issues, because of what we're going to do (I've tried)
- run your application
- press <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to get to `seamless mode`
- Now we're going to `save machine state`, not `power it off` (click X on VB minitoolbar or press <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>), that's because it starts with your application opened and in seamless mode by default (*just let it switch on the next run and select "don't show this message again"*), I'm sure that it is possible to start application on VM startup (probably `msconfig`) with seamless mode, without need of `saving machine state`, but for me that is good enough. **Make sure you unmount Guest Additions before this step as it would make your VM inaccessible (it's fixable, but why bother...)**

Now for the desktop entry (if you have any trouble with it check: [Creating a .desktop file for a new application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application)):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Adobe Acrobat Pro
Exec=VBoxManage startvm "name-of-your-vm"
Icon=path/to/your/desired/icon
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=VirtualBox
Categories=Office;
```

**It probably loads a little slower than via WINE, but this way it's more stable I guess. Plus it can be used for ANY application**

It will look something like this(you can theme both wine and VM):

[image: Seamless mode comparison]

Comment: I have tried to install Acrobat professional 9 instead of 8 using the wine way. I have followed all the steps but in vain.

Comment: I have followed all the steps you have mentioned. I have using winecfg the windows version display there was Windows 7 , but It shows runtime error, I have tried changing to Windows xp, with windows xp it opened for a while and it closed. After that there is no response when I tried open Acrobat.exe using wine.

Comment: Has that runtime error any specific number? That guide was appliable to AA Pro 8, so I don't know if it works for 9 as well. Try wine 32 bit prefix, if you are using 64 bit one...

Comment: The error message displaying on the terminal, but specific number for the runtime error is not visible in the dialog box
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (2)
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"MountMgr" failed to start: 2

Comment: fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"PlugPlay" failed to start: 2
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.762)
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.762)

Comment: fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.762)
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.762)
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.762)
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.762)
fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x32ef68 1 C) semi-stub
fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x32ed88 1 C) semi-stub

Comment: fixme:wer:WerRegisterMemoryBlock (0x149ee0 72) stub
fixme:heap:RtlCompactHeap (0x110000, 0x0) stub
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code 80000003 flags 0 addr 0x7bc7a12c

Comment: Are you sure you have installed all things correctly? Second... are you sure you are using 32 bit wine prefix?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I really appreciate it.  I have installed wine1.7.  And then I ran Acrobat professional 8.0 setup.exe and program is installed without any hitch.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed wine1.7 only. And then I ran Acrobat professional 8.0 setup.exe and program is installed without any hitch.