# How to create shortcut of executable on Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, shortcuts, taskbar

I have an executable file (here: Apache Directory Studio's `application/x-executable`) on my Ubuntu 15.04 vivid.

Now usually, when I want to place an application into my launcher, I simply drag and drop it there. But that doesn't work with the above mentioned executable; when I try to place it there, all icons are greyed out, except for the Files icon.

How can I place that exec on the Unity launcher?

Comment: try to create Desktop entry manually: http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application

Comment: @MiHa Yeah thanks, that looks like what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way imaginable:

Ordinarily start the application. When the icon appears in the Unity taskbar, right click the icon and chose `Lock to Launcher`.

[image: Unity: "Lock to Launcher"]

Note that this will create a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: You might want to add that this will *create* a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thank for the hint. I updated my answer.