# How to add options to unity launcher in Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04, unity, .desktop

I couldn't find format option when I right click on my pen-drive in Ubuntu 14.04.

I think it was available in earlier versions of Ubuntu. So now I would like to add <kbd>Format</kbd> option i.e when I right click on pen-drive it should show <kbd>Format</kbd> option along with other options. I know how to format a pen-drive using commands so I can write a script which will execute when <kbd>Format</kbd> option is clicked on GUI. I don't how to customize GUI, can anyone please provide me some resources related to this topic?

And if anyone knows the reason  why Ubuntu is not providing Format option directly?

Comment: Why don't you open "Disks" utility and format from there?

Comment: @Pilot6 By using "Disks" i can't format my pendrive as ext4 and it has some more defects

Comment: Why can't you? You can use gparted either way. It can do everything.

Comment: Just [edit the existing desktop file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application) for the pen drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a catch22 if referring to the nautilus format option for removable media like flash drives.

The option is there but will only show up if the drive is not mounted. However the default in nautilus is to automount drives when inserted & there is no unmount option once mounted.

Yet again some nonsense from Gnome & ignored by Ubuntu.

[image: format option on unmounted drive]

old bug that added the now bogus option - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1227440

So unmount your drive & you'll get the format option..