# Installing Skype on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, skype

I tried my best and viewed recommendations and that stuff on how to install Skype and ended up here, is there a problem? Anything?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Skype is already installed? Have you tried calling it from the command line? Just type skype and press enter? It strikes me that what you want is in fact a desktop entry for it, so it appears in the "start" menu?

Comment: Can you try running Skype? It seems that Skype is installed.

Answer (score 2):

As first it is already installed this is what your machine is telling you, simply run:

```
skype &
```

From a terminal:

after you have seen that this is there go back and fix your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

There fnd the lines you added with the wrong path with `cannical` in it and remove them, after that simply undo the `#` in front of the lines where it is called right `canonical`. Save and exit.

After that run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Skype is already installed, I believe what you actually want is a desktop entry for it, so here's a quick introduction for how to create one:

Create a new file in `~/.local/share/applications` to make it only available to your user, or `/usr/share/applications` to make it available to all users. Name it `skype.desktop`. Now edit the file, and place in it the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skype
Comment=Skype Internet Telephony
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U
Icon=skype.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/skype;
```

Depending on your Desktop Environment, this may or may not work, but you'll need to investigate desktop entries for your environment if you want to solve that...:

[Creating a .desktop file for a new application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application)

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/

Keep in mind that this probably isn't the "best" way to get a desktop entry. The better way would likely be to use the software centre where one would be created for you, but I assume you are using this method of installation because the software centre failed you.