# How do I create a desktop file out of a terminal command?

Tags: wine, .desktop

I want to create a `.desktop` file to run "world of warcraft" over wine. I can run the following command `wine /home/maciej/434_mini -opengl` to run it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new text file, paste this into the file, and save the file as `WoW.desktop`. Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application) post for more info.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=WoW
Comment=WorldofWarcraft
Exec=wine /home/maciej/434_mini -opengl
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Games,Applications
```

Comment: And what is `/home/maciej/434_mini -opengl`? is it supposed to start WoW? Why?

Comment: I forgot to add `wine`, but I just fixed it.

Comment: `wine` does not fix anything. Thes `.desktop` starts some program that is located in `/home/maciej/` directory that is called `434_mini`. This won't work.

Comment: Then what does `wine /home/maciej/434_mini -opengl` mean in the question?

Comment: Oops, sry. I did not see it. Can you make a small edit to your answer? I will upvote it. Without an edit, it does not let me.