# How do I install ChemCraft on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, executable, execute-command

Maybe I'm asking how to open an executable? I'm really not sure as their documentation seems sub-par. [See website](http://www.chemcraftprog.com/) for details- I've download the tarball and extracted, but there is no install script and I'm left absolutely confused. I'd appreciate some help- I've heard very good things about the program.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It is a little confusing, but I think I understand it well enough to help you.

<sub>DISCLAIMER: I looked through the files on WIndows, so I wasn't able to install or run it.</sub>

Opening the `tar.gz` file, I see another `.tar` file. Opening that, I see an `.sh` file, a `Chemcraft` folder and a `readme.txt` file.

Inside the ReadMe is this:

```
  To run Chemcraft, write correct paths in the "Chemcraft.sh" file (path
to the library ".../Chemcraft/lib/" and to the executable file
".../Chemcraft/Chemcraft").
  Note that the Linux version of Chemcraft has some significant
disadvantages. We were unable to make it as efficient as the Windows
version.
  Please email to support@chemcraftprog.com if you find any problems
with installation or running of Chemcraft.
```

From that, I gather that the script needs to be edited to reflect where the `ChemCraft` folder is. Obviously, to do that, you need to extract the `.tar` file.

Once you do that, find the `Chemcraft.sh` and double click it to edit.

Change the path in `KYLIX_BIN="/home/$USER/Chemcraft/Chemcraft/lib"` to reflect the path to the `lib` folder. For example, if you extracted to Downloads, it might be something like `/home/YOURUSERNAMEHERE/Downloads/Chemcraft/Chemcraft/lib`. Of course, this might be different, and you'll have to figure that part out yourself.

Also edit the path in `/home/$USER/Chemcraft/Chemcraft/Chemcraft $1` to reflect where it should be. Follow the example above.

Save the file, then open a terminal.

Run `chmod +x /path/to/Chemcraft.sh` to make the script executable.

Then run `/path/to/Chemcraft.sh` to run it.

---

By the way, this is the actual program, not something that gets installed. I recommend extracting the files to a somewhat permanent location, then editing the script to reflect that location.

If you want an easy way to run it, check out [how to make a .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application).

Comment: Here is what I get by doing that: jake@Bacon:~$ ./Chemcraft.sh 
/home/jake/Chemcraft/Chemcraft: symbol lookup error: /home/jake/Chemcraft/Chemcraft: undefined symbol: initPAnsiStrings

Comment: @jnowat I think that's an issue with Chemcraft, unfortunately, so you'll have to contact them.