# How to create a shortcut for sh file?

Tags: shortcuts, sh

I used to launch Android Studio by this steps:

1. Open Android Studio folder.
2. Open terminal there.
3. Confirm `sh studio.sh` command.

Can I lauch Android Studio from the Desktop by the 1 click?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/a/282187/119531). Give importance to the line: `Exec=/home/samuel/ugene-1.11.5/ugene -ui`. In your case change it to `path to your script`. Also, change the other relevant lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way to do this is:

after you open the program the same way you mentioned, right click on the program (from the programs bar/menu bar on the left) and click "Lock to Launcher".

Comment: Cannot find. Where is bar/menu ? On the left I clicked icon but nothing happens, so maybe I do in wrong place. https://imgur.com/a/Dgapg98

Answer (score 14):

Create a file ( [Desktop File](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) ) with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Android Studio 
Type=Application 
Icon=/PATH/TO/ICON/studio.png 
Exec=/PATH/TO/studio.sh 
Keywords=ide;android;studio;
```

Change `/PATH/TO/ICON/studio.png` and `/PATH/TO/studio.sh` accordingly.
save the file as: `android-studio.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications`

Now you'll be able to search in the [Dash](https://ubuntu.com/blog/introduction-to-unity-launcher) for Android Studio

---

> Android-Studio helps you of creating this entry file, within the Android Studio Welcome Page, tap the `Settings` icon and then, `Create Desktop Entry...`, the file will be created at `~/.local/share/applications/` path.

Comment: For whatever reason it is not working for me. I tried to write the path only with ```path/to/studio.sh``` and ``path/to/sh studio.sh``
Either way, not working and not able to launch from desktop icon

Comment: It worked, but after I change the file permissions to 644 with `chmod 644 file.desktop` and I also had my Exec= path not right, and when I fixed it to the correct path, the "Allow launching" appeared and I was able to add it as a favorite in the launcher.

Answer (score 2):

I use this :

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

I want to create launcher for Android Studio,
This is the simple way :
[image]

Open Alacarte. Choose New Item

[image]

Choose .sh File and Logo.. and Done.

[image]

Comment: Very easy! Thank you.

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 2292429 (aptd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: https://www.linuxsec.org/2018/12/mengatasi-error-e-could-not-get-lock.html