# xfce4-settings-manager don't show many configuration programs

Tags: 16.04, xfce, settings

I am having difficulties to configure the xfce4-settings-manager to show many configuration applications. Actually, the xfce4-settings-manager is showing only the configurations directly related to xfce4 and a few others.

The image showing the situation [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eN5V.png). On the left side, it can be seen the host system, where xfce4-settings-manager is showing the configurations correctly. On the right side, its the Virtual Machine with the problematic configuration. Under Sistema (System), many applications, as users-admin, software-properties-gtk and others are missing.

I tried to use dpkg-reconfigure xfce4-settings, which had no success.

When comparing the host and the virtual system, I simply can't find where the configurations are different which would hide the GNOME's options.

The system on the Virtual Machine was built from scratch and both systems are xenial, amd64. I thought the options would appear automatically. Have I done something wrong when configuring the system inside the Virtual Machine? Is there a package I should install or reconfigure to make all the configuration programs to appear?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to configure the xfce4-settings-manager to show the other settings applications. One package which has the correct files is the **xubuntu-default-settings**. Installing it and using the Xubuntu session made the menu work.

However, I did not wanted a Xubuntu session, but a xfce one. I started to search the files that xubuntu-default-settings install, and found the file:

> /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/xfce-settings-manager.menu

I read the files and, apparently, it is based on the configuration of the **.desktop** files.

This file is more sophisticated than the standard that comes with the **xfce4-settings**, being configured such way the applications not made specifically for xfce, but that serve to configure the system, are shown too. It's pretty interesting to see how the conditions are made on it, some search for additional informations and some are directly including or excluding the **.desktop** files.

User-wide, the configuration menu is at **~/.config/menus/xfce-settings-manager.menu**. System-wide, it searches **/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-settings-manager.menu**. For the Xubuntu session it is used **/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/xfce-settings-manager.menu**.

So, to make the xfce session have the settings appearing, I have copied the file from the **/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/** to **/etc/xdg/menus/**, so it becomes a "default" for the xfce session too. Looks like this file will persist, but another alternative is to copy it to **/etc/skel/.config/menus/**.

I could edit them to make them show specific entries, but the configuration of the Xubuntu's file is good enough to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this adding .desktop file in:

- System-wide dir: `/usr/share/applications`
- User dir: `~/.local/share/applications`

Create a `.desktop` file in one of this directories for the application you want to show in the settings menu and use the category labels for show itwhere you want.

For example for show the app icon in personal settings section use:

```
Categories=X-XFCE-SettingsDialog;X-XFCE-PersonalSettings;
```

This labels (categories) manage where desktop gonna show the icon for launch the app, if you add the label "Settings" it gonna show the icon in settings section in the panel menu.

```
Categories=Settings;X-XFCE-SettingsDialog;X-XFCE-PersonalSettings;
```

I don't really know about this issue, just messed up a bit for my own configs copying an editing existing .desktop files.

**References**

- This is all based on freedesktop, here you can find some info
  https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s03.html
- Here is also explained: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12957
- There is an opensource GUI that let you configure almost everything
  easy. https://launchpad.net/menulibre
- Nice answer about this: https://askubuntu.com/a/282187/1083128

Thanks to FurretUber reply, it help me to understand some things.