# Start own script via windows-key

Tags: 18.04, gnome, scripts, shortcut-keys

If I press the <kbd>windows</kbd> key I am able to type in the command which I want to execute. I like this autocomplete feature.

I have directory `~/scripts` which is in my PATH.

There is a script called `~/scripts/win.sh` which starts `rdesktop` to a remote terminal server with my preferred resolution.

I can call this script via the terminal.

But the autocomplete input which I see after pressing the <kbd>windows</kbd> key does not know this command.

I would like to avoid opening a terminal to call `win.sh`.

How can I start my script via the <kbd>windows</kbd> key?

I use default Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The applications you see when you press the windows key are defined in `.desktop` files stored in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/282187/354663) may help.

Comment: @danzel creating a .desktop file is a work-around. This is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: You can use `alacarte` to create menu entries (a.k.a desktop files) via GUI.