# How to make custom shortcuts to open or create any app

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, 19.04

I want to know the technique of making custom keyboard-shortcuts to open or create any app.

Comment: "open or create" are two very different things. How do you envisage creating "any app" by a custom shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Requirements

#### App or command

Install all of these like `sudo apt install wmctrl`

- xprob
- greb
- wmctrl

#### Information

`WM_CLASS` info of the app.

### Instructions

#### Creating `WM_CLASS` for any app

To do this, you need to make desktop app.

- Type `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/<appname>.desktop`
- And fill these section what you want to do, I suggest you to look [these post](https://askubuntu.com/a/282187/898692)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Appname
GenericName=Appname
Comment=
Exec=
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=
Categories=
Keywords=
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=
StartupWMClass=
```

#### Getting `WM_CLASS` of any app

- First type terminal to find `WM_CLASS` of any app `xprop | grep WM_CLASS`
- After <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, click the app, which you want to make shortcut for
- You will see a return like `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-terminal-server", "Gnome-terminal"`
- Copy first string which is `gnome-terminal-server` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

#### Making shortcut

- Open shortcuts with typing `shortcut` to search panel
- Click `+` icon the bottom of the opened window
- Set any name which u want to **name** section
- Type `bash -c "wmctrl -xa <wm_class> || <wm_class>` to **command** section
- Finally, click shortcut and set your custom shortcut :)