# How to make Dash recognise an AppImage as a runnable program?

Tags: unity-dash, appimage

I downloaded an AppImage and set it's permissions to execute.

When I start typing it's name in Dash and click on it, the containing folder is opened rather than the AppImage is run.

[image]

How can I make it behave the same way it works for applications installed with snap?

PS: I am not sure it is called Dash in the latest Ubuntu releases, what I mean is the global search menu which opens when pressing the Win key. Feel free to correct me and I will edit the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a .desktop file for a new application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application) - You should create a `.desktop` file under `usr/share/applications`

Comment: @Nmath Yes, Thanks!