# How can I show downloaded apps icons on desktop

Tags: icons

I just install ubuntu . How can ı see my spotify vs code's icons on my desktop . Is there a shortcut for it or terminal command ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop) or https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application

Comment: no still cant do anything when ı try alt + f2 just open a panel that says run command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find their corresponding `*.desktop` files in the `/usr/share/applications/` directory.

Then copy these `*.desktop` files to your `/home/<YOURUSERNAME>/Desktop/` (also known as `~/Desktop/`) directory.

They will show up on the desktop, but initially without their correct icon.

Right-click on them, and in the appearing context menu, check "Allow launching". That will restore their icon, plus allows mouseclicks to open the corresponding apps.

---

This may not be necessary, but if above does not seem to work, be ready to do this as well, as additional measure.

Install the Gnome Tweaks app:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Open this app from the apps-overview screen, go to its "Extensions" tab, and activate the "Desktop icons" extension.

Comment: "Open this app from the apps-overview screen, go to its "Extensions" tab, and activate the "Desktop icons" extension." And then?

Comment: Ah, maybe log out and log back in ... Or reload the shell by hitting Alt+F2 (Run command dialog) then putting a single `r` in there and Enter.

Comment: Sorry , I am new . Did you mean reboot?

Comment: Well, reboot is not necessary. In the top right corner's power menu, right next to "Power off", you will find an option to "Log out". That logout is sufficient. It does not restart the entire machine, just tears down your session. When you log back in, you start a brand new session. It's faster than a full reboot.

Comment: I did log out now. But when ı go applications end right click to for ex spotify. There is still nothing. Or I cant select and put on desktop like windows .Please help me.

Comment: Have you copied the `spotify-or-how-its-called.desktop` file to your `/home/<YOURUSERNAME>/Desktop/` folder?

Comment: No . Where can ı find any apps .desktop file .Thanks for patience

Comment: Open terminal. Execute `cd /usr/share/applications/` Then execute `ls -l | grep spotify` This will show you the relevant files. Then run `cp however-is-the-actual-file-called.desktop ~/Desktop/`. That should do it.

Comment: İts running now. Big thanks for all sir