# How do I create icon launch for Firefox

Tags: firefox, icons

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10, which doesn't come with Firefox, I downloaded it from the [official side](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/download/thanks/), then I extract it and navigate to the source code, I run `./firefox` on the terminal and firefox is working fine, but when I close it I have to do the same prosses again, how can I create launch icon  for firefox?

Comment: 21.10 comes with Firefox. It is preinstalled as snap, but you can remove that and use `apt` to install the deb version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a .desktop file for a new application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application). By the way, you can simply install latest firefox with `sudo apt install firefox`. It comes with the launch icon.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will be to install `menulibre` to create your own menu entry. Ubuntu does not by default come with a tool for creating menu entries.

The manual way involves creating a `.desktop` launcher file in `.local/share/applications`. You can create a file from scratch, or copy and adapt an existing one.