# Add terminal application to favorites

Tags: gnome, 21.10

How can I add a terminal application (such as `less` or `python`) if that application doesn't appear in the list when I press the "Show Applications" button?

Comment: Create a .desktop file for them. https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a terminal application to your Favorites, you first need to create a valid launcher for it. Once created, it can be pinned as favorite.

You can create a `.desktop` launcher for terminal commands when you set `Terminal=true`. That option will attempt to open a terminal to run the command specified on the `Exec=` line.

The launcher will appear in your menu only if it is valid and located in `~/.local/share/applications` or an `applications` directory under one of the directories listed in XDG_DATA_DIRS,e.g., `/usr/local/share/applications`,

An example of such `.desktop` file is given below.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Htop
GenericName=Process Viewer
Comment=Show System Processes
Icon=htop
Exec=htop
Terminal=true
Categories=System;Monitor;ConsoleOnly;
Keywords=system;process;task
```

As the executable exists in one of the directories of the PATH, specifying its name on the `Exec=` line is sufficient. Else, provide the full pathname.

When the icon is installed in `~/.icons`, `~/.local/share/icons` or in an icons directory under one of the directories listed in XDG_DATA_DIRS,e.g.,  `/usr/local/share/icons`, specifying the file name, without extension, of the icon file is sufficient. Else, specify a full path name.

Lines such as `Comments` and `Generic name` are optional.